# How to use multiple string methods like .upper after .split?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can I use .split and .upper in one or two lines?

This works.

```
print('Hello, World.'.split())
```

How is something like this possible?

```
print('Hello, World.'.split().upper())
```

Why do I can't to call multiple string methods after one call to .split?

Comment: You can do the opposite: 'Hello, World.'.upper().split().  After split, it's no longer a string, so you can't call upper on it.

Comment: Thank you that seems to work. Awesome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on Max's point, you can inspect these calls using `dis.dis`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("'Hello, world.'.upper().split()")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello, world.')
              2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (upper)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (split)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("[x.lower() for x in 'Hello, world.'.split()]")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x1090e1420, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('Hello, world.')
              8 LOAD_ATTR                0 (split)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the first approach - converting everything to uppercase *then* splitting - has fewer steps and is likely more efficient. Some time-tests will demonstrate this further...

```
_-Air:~ _$ cat test.py 
import time

s = 'Hello, world.'
n = 10000000

t0 = time.time()
for _ in range(n):
    s.upper().split()
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)

t0 = time.time()
for _ in range(n):
        [x.upper() for x in s.split()]
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
_-Air:~ _$ python3 test.py 
4.7296531200408936
8.44889211654663
```

And we can also assert the equivalence of both approaches:

```
_-Air:~ _$ python3 -c 'assert "Hello, World.".upper().split() == [x.upper() for x in "Hello, World.".split()]'
```

Since no `AssertionError` is raised, we know these are equal objects.